# Staging Slot processing messages for Web App background task

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots

I am using Azure App service plan to host web App which process Service Bus Topic message.
I am using Azure Function App also which has http trigger to execute Event grid data.
Both Web App(App Service Plan) and Function App(Elastic Premium plan) have staging slots in production.

At the time of swapping slot I observed stgaing slot for web app is processing message. Is this expected behaviour?
For function app staging slot, I am not observing this behaviour. Why so ?

Comment: is your app service running a webjob to consume messages?

Comment: @Juanma Feliu - No, App Service is running as web app (REST API) not web job.

Comment: @Juanma Feliu - Sorrey, I am using IHostedService so it will run as web job in web apps

Comment: Updated my answer with code for webjobs. Wish it can help you adapting it to your own code.

Comment: Code is for webjobs not for IHostedService but it can give you an idea how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an App Setting in each slot called "IsStaging" with true and false values then when app service warms up (Startup or method consuming messages) stop requests so messages are not consumed from the Staging slot.

```
                if (CurrentConfiguration.IsStaging)
                {
                   logger.LogWarn("Staging slot cannot consume messages");
                   return;
                }
```

**UPDATE for WebJob**:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JobHost host = CreateJobHost();
            if (CurrentConfiguration.IsStaging)
            {
                host.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("DoStagingInfiniteLoop"));
            }
            else
            {
                host.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("ProcessQueue"));
            }
        }


        private static JobHost CreateJobHost()
        {
            JobHostConfiguration jobHostConfig = new JobHostConfiguration();
            jobHostConfig.DashboardConnectionString = "DashboardCS";
            jobHostConfig.StorageConnectionString = "StorageCS";

            var JobHost = new JobHost(jobHostConfig);
            return JobHost;
        }


        [NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public static void DoStagingInfiniteLoop(TextWriter logger, CancellationToken token)
        {
            const int LOOP_TRACE_INTERVAL = 10000;
            ProcessLogger.WriteTrace("This is a staging environment, waiting...");
            while (true)
            {
                Task.Delay(LOOP_TRACE_INTERVAL).Wait(token);
            }
        }

        [NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public static void ProcessQueue(TextWriter logger, CancellationToken token)
        {
            //Your processing code here
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you stop the slot, otherwise it will be in the running state (can receive message). If you don’t want it to receive information, you should stop it.

Comment: Will staging slot process data at the time of swaping from staging to production for both Function App and Web App ?

Comment: @AmitAgrawal yes, if you don't want it process, please stop.

Comment: @ Bowman Zhu - I observed processing only swapping of slot which we can't avoid . We are deploying to staging slot then swapping to prod slot. After swapping no processing by Staging slot so if staging slot is running then no matters but concnern is we dont want to process message by staging slot at the time of swapping.

Comment: Why staging slot process data in case of web app not in case of function App while swapping from staging to production takes place ?

Comment: @AmitAgrawal I think the problem is that the web app still allows external requests even in the slot state. But the HttpTrigger in the function app rejects external requests when the function app is in the slot state.