# How to make Service Bus processor work only on the production slot and not on the deployment slot in .NET Core 6 microservice deployed on Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a C# .Net Core 6 microservice deployed on Azure. In this app, I have a connection to a Servicebus processor.
My problem is that the Servicebus is processing the messages not only in the production slot but also in the deployment slot, which creates many problems for me.
I have tried to stop the processor when receiving a message if I detect that we are running on the deployment slot but that throws an exception and causes losing the data of that specific message.

Does anyone know how can I make the Servicebus processor work only on the production slot and not on the deployment slot?

Adding an example code that contains the central part of mine.

This is the message reciever class:

```
public class MessageReceiver<T> : MessageReceiverBase where T : IIntegrationMessageQueue
{
    private readonly ILogger<MessageReceiver<T>> _logger;
    private readonly IIntegrationMessageHandler<T> _processingService;
    private readonly ServiceBusConfigurationOptions _serviceBusConfiguration;
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient ;

    private ServiceBusClient? client;

    private ServiceBusProcessor? processor = null;


    public MessageReceiver(ILogger<MessageReceiver<T>> logger, ServiceBusConfigurationOptions serviceBusConfiguration, IIntegrationMessageHandler<T> processingService, TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _processingService = processingService;
        _serviceBusConfiguration = serviceBusConfiguration;
        _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
        
    }


    private async Task InitializeListener()
    {
        try
        {
            _telemetryClient.TrackTrace($"InitializeListener");
            Queue queue = _serviceBusConfiguration.Queues.FirstOrDefault();

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queue?.Name))
                {
                    await CreateQueueIfNotExistsAsync(queue);

                    var clientOptions = new ServiceBusClientOptions()
                    {
                        TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
                        
                    };

                    var processorOptions = _serviceBusConfiguration.processorOptions != null ? _serviceBusConfiguration.processorOptions : new ServiceBusProcessorOptions();

                    client = new ServiceBusClient(_serviceBusConfiguration.ConnectionString, clientOptions);

                    processor = client.CreateProcessor(queue.Name, processorOptions);
                    isListening = true;
                    _telemetryClient.TrackTrace($"created processor for {queue.Name} queue");
                }
        }   
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private async Task CreateQueueIfNotExistsAsync(Queue queue)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queue?.Name))
            {
                var client = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(_serviceBusConfiguration.ConnectionString);
                                   
                if (!await client.QueueExistsAsync(queue.Name))
                {
                    await client.CreateQueueAsync(queue.Name);

                }

                if(_serviceBusConfiguration.LockDuration != null)
                {
                    if (_serviceBusConfiguration.processorOptions == null || _serviceBusConfiguration.processorOptions.ReceiveMode != ServiceBusReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete)
                    {
                        QueueProperties queueProperties = await client.GetQueueAsync(queue.Name);
                        if (queueProperties != null && queueProperties.LockDuration !=  _serviceBusConfiguration.LockDuration)
                        {
                            queueProperties.LockDuration = (TimeSpan)_serviceBusConfiguration.LockDuration;
                            await client.UpdateQueueAsync(queueProperties);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message = args.Message;
            try
            {
                string body = message.Body.ToString();
                await _processingService.Message(body);
                await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
                operation.Telemetry.Success = false;
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            cancellationToken = stoppingToken;
            await InitializeListener();
            if (processor != null)
            {
                processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
                processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
                await StartReceivingMessagesAsync(processor, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private async Task StartReceivingMessagesAsync(ServiceBusProcessor processor, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            if (processor != null)
            {
                await processor.StartProcessingAsync(stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The AddAzureServiceBusRegistration function:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddAzureServiceBusRegistration<T>(this IServiceCollection services, ServiceBusConfigurationOptions serviceBusConfigurationOptions)  where T : IIntegrationMessageQueue  
    {
        services.AddHostedService<MessageReceiver<T>>(sp =>
        {
            var messageProcessingService = sp.GetRequiredService<IIntegrationMessageHandler<T>>();
            
            var logger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MessageReceiver<T>>>();

            TelemetryClient telemetryClient = sp.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();
            return new MessageReceiver<T>(logger, serviceBusConfigurationOptions, messageProcessingService, telemetryClient);
        });

        return services;
    }
```

And this is the way I register the servicebus on the Program.cs:

```
string connectionString = "exampleKey";
List<string> queueNames = new List<string>() { "QueueExampleName" };
ServiceBusReceiveMode receiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock;
ServiceBusConfigurationOptions serviceBusConfigurationOptions = new ServiceBusConfigurationOptions()
{
    ConnectionString = connectionString,
    Queues = queueNames.Select(n => new Queue() { Name = n, Sub = true }).ToList(),
    processorOptions = new ServiceBusProcessorOptions
    {
        MaxConcurrentCalls = 100,
        PrefetchCount = 3200,
        ReceiveMode = receiveMode,
        
    },
    LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200)
};
builder.Services.AddAzureServiceBusRegistration<Message>(serviceBusConfigurationOptions);

builder.Services.AddTransient<IIntegrationMessageHandler<Message>, MessageHandler>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection string you're supplying to `ServiceBusConfigurationOptions` should read from the configuration that's defined as slot-specific (pinned to a specific slot). If not, all slots will share the same configuration value and connect to the same namespace, essentially acting as competing consumers, processing messages.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. While using a slot-specific configuration, including the connection string, can help isolate the Service Bus namespace between slots, it doesn't address the dynamic switching of the Service Bus processor when moving between the deployment and production slots. Do you have any suggestions for this issue?

Comment: Slots act as environments. So when you deploy to your "test" slot, you will have a different version of code running against your test ASB namespace. When you swap, you'll swap the deployed bits between the environments, not the settings. And since you're swapping the bits (implementation), your application will have a refresh, during which it will pick up the current slot's configuration. You might want to look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots#swap-operations) for the explanation of the steps that are taking place.

Comment: @SeanFeldman Is this about right? Your source code could detect if it's in a staging slot before wiring up the servicebus connections, and not to wire them up if in staging (for example). The staging app can then run without consuming messages. When the swap is then triggered, there will then effectively be 2 apps in production, but DNS changes are only reset once the swapped app warms up without failure (and at which point should have now wired up the servicbus connections, as it is restarted in the Prod slot). Briefly, there could still then be 2 competing apps for the servicebus messages...

Comment: I haven't tried detecting wherever the code is in the staging slot or not. The whole point is not to worry about the environment, knowing the right settings will be read. But if you have something working, please share.

Comment: It's basically the same concept that you shared - though in my case I have json config files (not app config) that determine which topics to post to, and which to subscribe to for various microservices. In my case it would be easier to have a sticky app config setting that is then read in code to determine whether to wire up the handlers or not. Not implemented yet - still researching, and between your answer and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66805950/77150 that seems to be the best for my case. I'm banking on the staging app restarting when moved to the prod slot though.

Comment: I am curious to see what you'll come up with.